# how to get http_referer in nginx mod_perl

Tags: perl, nginx, mod-perl

I have an nginx mod perl module which gets data and takes action based on parameters 
in my script I am not able to get the http referer

I am trying

```
$r->header_in("http_referer")   # Gives an undefined string
$r->headers_in()    # func not defined
```

How can I get all the headers passed by the http client inside my function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$r->header_in("http_referer")   # Gives an undefined string
```

The request header field you are looking for  is not `http_referer` but `referer`, i.e. use`header_in("referer")`. See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) for more on this field.